using ansible facts or json_query, how do i get this mac address out of this json?
so i got json back from an openstack server query, but need to extract the mac address for the server. Getting the name and IP is easy enough but the mac address is hidden behind the vlan and a colon. Can you please help to identify either a json_query or maybe ansible fact play that will get me just the mac address as plain text?
Below actual play for this, but getting the mac address fails.
---

- name: Test getting data from openstack
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
   server_name: haproxy1
  tasks:
   - name: Retrieve list of all servers in this project
     os_server_info:
       auth:
         auth_url: '{{ os_auth_url }}'
         username: '{{ os_username }}'
         password: '{{ os_password }}'
         project_name: '{{ os_project_name }}'
         user_domain_name: '{{ os_user_domain_name }}'
         project_domain_name: "{{ os_project_domain_name }}"
       validate_certs: false
     register: servers


   - name: get the server MAC address table
     set_fact:
       server_mac_table: "{{servers | community.general.json_query(jmespath_mac) }}"
     vars:
       jmespath_mac:  "servers[?name == '{{ server_name }}'].addresses"
     register: results

   - debug:
       var=results

   - name: get only the server MAC address
     set_fact:
       any_server_mac: "{{servers | community.general.json_query(jmespath_mac) | replace('[','' ) | replace(']','' ) }}"
     vars:
       jmespath_mac:  "servers[?name == '{{ server_name }}'].{addresses.VLAN-199.0S-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr}"
     register: results

   - debug:
       var=results

so the task to get the mac address json produces the below output.
TASK [get the server MAC address table] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "results": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "server_mac_table": [
                {
                    "VLAN-199": [
                        {
                            "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:0b:ab:f2:9a:20",
                            "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
                            "addr": "192.128.120.131",
                            "version": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}

So, I need to construct a play for json_query or ansible fact to replace this play

name: get only the server MAC address
which does not work and I've tried many combinations of both but not getting just the mac address.

your help would be greatly appreciated

ansible_facts.server_mac_table.0['VLAN-199'].0['OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr']

Hi, The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'server_mac_table'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'server_mac_table'   or just printing that line just prints that line.

Then, the JSON output you are displaying here is not what you really have, please [edit] your question to make it a [mre].

I've added the play..

Pro-tip one: do provide debug of your actual input (which is servers , not results). Pro-tip two: don't register a set_fact, use the fact you did set, rather.

I can't dump the whole servers object here.  Ansible recognizes the data as a list,, but when printing the list it shows as one large list item in the list. The server object is a JSON. but the JSON structure is not as expected because of that colon in OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr, and also when selecting the key addresses for [0] it returns all values, and I'm unable to select the individual mac_addr value.

"servers": [
{
"access_ipv4": "172.122.110.62",
"access_ipv6": "",
"addresses": {
"VLAN-199": [
{
"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:8a:4d:fd:39:20",
"OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
"addr": "172.122.110.62",
"version": 4
}
]
},

if unable to do this with json_query or ansible facts, I'll just get the mac address from openstack port list and parse those results. Requires a shell and less efficient, but easier to parse.

I would go {{ (servers | selectattr('name', '==', server_name) | last). addresses['VLAN-199'].0['OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr'] }}, from what you are giving, but without a [mre], ... The trick is kinda always the same, if you have special characters in your keys, use dict['special.char.keys'], rather than the dot-notation. Further reading: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use

"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'. 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'

So,


name: try this new one
set_fact:
get_mac:  "{{servers | community.general.json_query(jmespath_new) }}"
vars:
jmespath_new: "servers[?name == '{{ server_name }}']. addresses"
register: newresults


debug:
var=newresults


gets everything, but the below gets nothing


name: try this new one
set_fact:
get_mac:  "{{servers | community.general.json_query(jmespath_new) }}"
vars:
jmespath_new: "servers[?name == '{{ server_name }}']. addresses.[*]"
register: newresults


debug:
var=newresults



the original server object... using type_debug...
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "list"
}
TASK [modify to_nice_json]
ok: [localhost]
TASK [now what are you after to_nice_json] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "NativeJinjaUnsafeText"

I think the problem is that this json is not properly formed ... no index , just curly brackets.. another output from an ansible openstack module command gives the same problem .ok: [localhost] => {
"worker_port_1_config": {
"changed": true,
"failed": false,
"port": {
"allowed_address_pairs": [],
"binding_host_id": "",
"binding_profile": {},
"binding_vif_details": {},

The only output that could be parsed properly was jmespath_ip:  "servers[?name == '{{ bastion_hostname }}'].access_ipv4 | [0]" because of the location of access_ipv4,  which is an under an index , ok: [bastion1 -> localhost] => {
"servers": {
"changed": false,
"failed": false,
"servers": [
{
"access_ipv4": "192.168.130.62",
"access_ipv6": "",
"addresses": {
So is this a problem with the output of the ansible openstack module or the output given by the openstack it is talking to?

Ok, got it , tested on a diffrent output for the os_port module.. this worked         - name: get the mac address for the bootstrap-port
set_fact:
bootstrap_mac: "{{ bootstrap_port_config | community.general.json_query(jmespath) | replace('[','' ) | replace(']','' ) }}"
vars:
jmespath: "port.mac_address"
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "mac address for bootstrap node is: fa:16:3e:0e:b2:4d"
}
Thanks
